# ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated, a part of my query it's failing

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select 'BETWEEN TO_DATE(''' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00') || ''', ''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'') AND TO_DATE(''' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE + 1, 'dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00')
```

Is there something bad in this Query? It's not the full query it's just a part of it. I'ts throwing this error:

```
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

Comment: No `FROM` clause.

Comment: @jarlh it's just a part of a Query. I¡m only showing the error from the part which it's failing

Comment: I get ORA-01821: date format not recognized. I.e. no quoted string  problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the q-quoting mechanism.

By the way, your code can be simplified to

```
select q'[between trunc(current_date) and trunc(current_date + 1)]' result
from dual;
```

No need to `to_char` and then `to_date` `current_date`; it already *is* `DATE` datatype, just remove (truncate to midnight) time component.

---

By the way #2, format mask you used is wrong; should be `dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss` (not `dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00`)

---

If you insist (though, I don't know why would you), then

```
select q'[between to_date(to_char(current_date    , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')]' ||
       q'[    and to_date(to_char(current_date + 1, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')]'
    as result 
from dual;
```

Does it work? Yes:

```
SQL> select q'[between to_date(to_char(current_date    , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')]' ||
  2         q'[    and to_date(to_char(current_date + 1, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')]'
  3      as result
  4  from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
between to_date(to_char(current_date    , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd/mm/yyyy
hh24:mi:ss')    and to_date(to_char(current_date + 1, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')


SQL>
```

Now copy/paste the *result* into another query and verify it:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dual
  3  where sysdate
  4  -- this is the "result":
  5  between to_date(to_char(current_date    , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')    and to_date(to_char(current_date + 1, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  6  ;

D
-
X

SQL>
```

Didn't fail, eh?

Comment: Why you ignore the part of "dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00" ? In my query i just want one day and plus one day. Maybe i'm wrong, just asking

Comment: I told you - that's **invalid** format mask. Use the 1st code I suggested: `between trunc(current_date) and trunc(current_date + 1)`